# In the sentence "She ate pizza at school," is "school" an indirect object?

Tags: objects

I know that in the sentence "I'm doing a project for school," "school" is indeed the indirect object, but in the title sentence, is "school" a indirect object there as well?

Comment: The one you ask about is the easy one (though it's ambiguous: was this habitual or a one-off?) A locative PP. //  Though 'I'm doing mum a favour' (which may be transformed to 'I'm doing a favour for mum') is ditransitive/benefactive, with _mum_, bless her, being the _one who who benefits from / gets something as a result of an action_, 'I'm doing a project for school' has a different sense of 'for': the school cannot easily be seen as a benefactive. 'I'm doing school a project' doesn't work. 'For school' equates to 'as part of my schoolwork'.

Comment: How in the world can you do school a project?

Comment: (1) _school_ is not an indirect object in "I'm doing a project for school". (2) It's not an indirect object in "She ate pizza at school", either. (3) Indirect objects only occur with verbs of transfer (_give, send, say, toss, .._), and they always refer to whatever (more often, **who**ever) received the direct object that was given, sent, or tossed by the subject. (4) It's not just **any** noun after the direct object that's an indirect object -- it has to be the direct object of the right verb, and it has to refer to the receiver.

Comment: @Jesus Johnson. Do you understand now that "school" is not an indirect object in either of you examples, but is object of the prepositions "at" / "for".

Comment: No it isn't.  But in the sentence "She threw the pizza at the teacher", the headteacher would be the indirect object.

Comment: CGEL's analysis of ditransitive verbs includes benefactives (often interchangeable with a sentence containing a for-phrase), and also includes in its 'non-replaceable by a PP construction' category such semantically alien examples as 'The council refused him permission to build' / 'He envied her her quick wit'.  // But, IMO. while 'I'm doing Pru an omelette' is an acceptable informal ditransitive (benefactive) usage,  'I'm doing school a project' is unacceptable. Verbs such as 'refuse', 'deny', 'envy', licensing S-V-DO-IO, but not indicating active transfer or benefit, are rare.

Comment: @Tuffy You're wrong! In "She threw the pizza at the teacher", "the teacher" is object of the preposition "at" **not** indirect object of "threw"

Comment: Right, @BillJ. Now, “She threw the teacher the pizza,” that’s a different thing… *viz*. an indirect-object thing.

Answer (score 1):

No.

"At school" is a prepositional phrase indicating the location of the action. The word "school" is the object of the preposition. It is not an object (direct or indirect) of the verb.

Similarly "for school" is a prepositional phrase indicating the purpose of the action. Prepostional phrases are very flexible and can have lots of different meanings and roles.

Proper indirect objects are found in ditransitive verbs: "I gave Peter the ball".  Both "Peter" and "the ball" are objects;  Peter is the indirect object.  These can often be rephrased with a prepositional phrase giving the same meaning: "I gave the ball to Peter". But this does not make all nouns in prepositional phrases into indirect objects.